# How To Save values to database using KENDO GRID MVVM?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mvvm

kindly tell me how to make inline update and delete button?
Here is my HTML CODE :

```
  <div id="example">

    <div data-role="grid"
         data-editable="true"
         data-toolbar="['create', 'save']"
         data-columns="[

          { 'field': 'Id', 'width': 100 },
                  { 'field': 'ShortName', 'width': 100 },
              { 'field': 'FullName', 'width': 100 },
           { 'field': 'ContactPerson', 'width': 100 },
           { 'field': 'Adress1', 'width': 100 },
           { 'field': 'CompanyCity', 'width': 100 },
              { 'field': 'CompanyCountry', 'width': 100 },
              { 'field': 'ZipPostCode', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'TelArea', 'width': 100 },

         ]"
         data-bind="source: products,
                        visible: isVisible,
                        events: {
                         save: onSave
                        }"
         style=" height: 400px"></div>


</div>
```

It succesfully displays the data using transport read:

```
  document.onreadystatechange= function () {

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    isVisible: true,
    onSave: function (e) {

        },
        products: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                model: {
                    Id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "int" },
                        ShortName: { type: "string" },
                        FullName: { type: "string" },
                        ContactPerson: { type: "string" },
                        CompanyCity: { type: "string" },
                        CompanyCountry: { type: "string" },
                        ZipPostCode: { type: "string" },
                        TelArea: { type: "string" }

                    }
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Companies/GetAllCompanies",
                    dataType: "json"
                },

                //update: {
                //    url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/update",
                //    dataType: "jsonp"
                //},
                create: {
         //HOW TO PERFOM CREATE BY INLINE BUTTON OR ALSO HOW TO STORE VALUES
           },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models)      };
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
kendo.bind(document.getElementById("example"), viewModel);
        }
```

here is my save controller controller code

```
   [HttpPost]
       public void SaveDefCompny(DefCompanyDTO DfCmpny1)
    {
        DefCompany dfcmpny2 = new DefCompany();
        RPDBEntities db = new RPDBEntities();
        db.DefCompanies.Add(DfCmpny1);
        dfcmpny2.saveDefCompany();
    }
```

Tell me how to make save values of grid to database using inline save button and it make an array of grid values and save it in database by calling controller [post]?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set editMode to inline and add command colum for edit and delete button.

```html
<div id="example">

    <div data-role="grid"
         data-editable="inline"
         data-columns="[

          { 'field': 'Id', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'ShortName', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'FullName', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'ContactPerson', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'Adress1', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'CompanyCity', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'CompanyCountry', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'ZipPostCode', 'width': 100 },
          { 'field': 'TelArea', 'width': 100 },
          { command: ['edit', 'destroy'], title: '&nbsp;', width: '250px' }],           

         ]"
         data-bind="source: products"
         style="height: 400px"></div>
</div>
```

Then specify url for update and destroy requests and change batch mode for false because you send one object only after edit. Parameter map now sends only edited row.

```js
document.onreadystatechange= function () {

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        products: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                model: {
                    Id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "int" },
                        ShortName: { type: "string" },
                        FullName: { type: "string" },
                        ContactPerson: { type: "string" },
                        CompanyCity: { type: "string" },
                        CompanyCountry: { type: "string" },
                        ZipPostCode: { type: "string" },
                        TelArea: { type: "string" }

                    }
                }
            },
            batch: false,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Companies/GetAllCompanies",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {
                   url: "/api/Companies/Update", // here you need correct api url
                   dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/api/Companies/Delete", // here you need correct api url
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && data) {
                        return { kendo.stringify(data) };
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
    
  kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);

}
```

Comment: can i perform crud in same way deletion

Comment: problem is onclicking inline button control cannot move toward update or destroy i have debuged many times....what id in html code i give to commands button you added. the error is cannot read property data

Comment: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined KINDLY HELP WHILE updating or saving